# How can I use the dvdbackup tool in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, software, dvd

I want to use 'dvdbackup' tool in my Mac OS X, however its specification is too simple. I would like to know how to back up my whole DVD, can anyone give my some example or advice step by step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page:

`dvdbackup -M -i/dev/dvd -o/my/dvd/backup/dir/` This action creates a valid DVD-Video structure that can be burned to a DVD-/+R(W) with help of mkisofs version 1.11a27 or later 
 http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/dvdbackup

Honestly I have never used this tool on Mac OS X, if you want to do some dvd ripping and this keeps frustrating you, [Handbrake](http://www.macworld.com/article/157590/2011/02/how_to_rip_dvd_handbrake.html) is pretty good, or you can even use the built in [Disk Utility](http://www.kenstone.net/fcp_homepage/making_dvd_copies.html) to do a image backup of said DVD.

Comment: Anytime my frand.